# Evaluats this integral

Tags: integration

Evaluate : $$\int _0^1 \frac{5x}{\left(5x^2+6\right)^2} \mathrm{d} x$$

not sure how to solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** let $5x^2+6=u\implies 10x\ dx=du$ or $x\ dx=\frac{du}{10}$ $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{5x}{(5x^2+6)^2}\ dx=\int_{6}^{11}\frac{5}{u^2}\frac{du}{10}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{6}^{11}u^{-2}du$$

Comment: I got $-\frac{1}{2\left(5x^2+6\right)}+C$ , is this correct?

Comment: yes, absolutely correct, apply the limits from $0$ to $1$ to get the numerical value